# Why isn't input synced with state in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I'm making a form generator that uses a JSON schema to build a form and I've ran into an issue.

If I make a controlled input and I call `getForms` method (method that generates the form) on each render it updates the value of input from state as expected.

Great. But, I don't want the algorithm that generates the form from JSON schema to be called on every render.

I tried storing the form in a class variable or in a state but it didn't work as expected. When the input is changed the state is updated correctly, but it didn't update the form input.

Here is an example of my problem: https://codesandbox.io/embed/q8zl5p9x5q

Edit: examining the object there is only one difference -- the owner property is not set when i render input element from a variable. Could that be it ?

What I need is that I only generate the form once, since it has complex logic behind it it will be a performance hit that it needs to run it on every keystroke, and then update **just** their values from the state.

The value is not important when the `getForms` method is called. I just needs to be equal to the state the the input is changed.

For now only things that come to my mind are using refs and cloning the element with `React.cloneElement` and adding state to the value.

Comment: I think `componentShouldUpdate` may help you here; https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html

Comment: Hmm.. How exactly could it work for my example? Render need to be run, but not the method that generates the input.

Comment: It seems that because `getForms` relies on state to generate the input, then it really needs to run every time the state is updated. Perhaps it'd be easier if you added a direct question as to what you need?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: `getForms` should be actually a separate component, into which you should pass the state as a property. You are making it too complicated for yourself.

Comment: @Sulthan if it were a separate component, and the state were passed in, that other component would still need to update using `getForms` everytime the state was updated, because the state is used in the `getForms` function

Comment: It seems to me that you'd be better off looking at ways to avoid having such complicated logic in a render function. Try taking any logic not related to the rendering of the form out of that function.

Comment: At a mid point in my algorithm I'm receiving a list of all form elements as a flat array. I could do a `React.cloneElement` there to add value from the state before passing it on to styling and grouping algorithm. Good enough solution?

Comment: @CodeBreaker I'm afraid I don't follow 100%; but it seems like a good enough idea to at least try it. I feel like this problem is more high level, either the value is or isn't required as part of the algorithm which takes a long time. If it isn't, it should be separated, and this could then be avoided

Comment: @OliverRadini The value of the input is not important at a point of form creation. It just needs to be equal to the state value `onChange`. But, this might be a separate question, how do I *link* the input value to a state after the component has been created? I updated the codesandbox with an example of `React.cloneElement`

Comment: @CodeBreaker I suppose the question, then, is whether it's possible to bind the value of an input after it has been rendered?

Comment: @OliverRadini It appears so. Should I open a new question?

Comment: @CodeBreaker I think that, to be honest, you'll get a much better response if you do